# Failed to load class SparkDemo on spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a simple Hello World program with Scala to run on on Apache Spark 3.1.1. However I am getting the following error on spark-submit

[image]

I am using the below command:

```
spark-submit --class SparkDemo --master local --executor-memory 800m /Users/souravhazra/Downloads/SparkDemo.jar
```

This is my Scala code:

```
object SparkDemo {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {    
       println("Hello World")
   }
}
```

This is my build.sbt

[image]

I am stuck in this issue over a couple of days. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169464/error-failed-to-load-class-main-using-spark-submit)?

Comment: Tried....not working

Comment: what did you try from that post?

Comment: I tried, making the versions same for all the dependencies as that of scala but still not working.